# Statistic count not working with API call

Tags: nodes

There isn't much info around it, but when I'm using `Statistic module` to get the views per node it's only working when I'm visiting the page of the specific `node`. When I'm using an `API` call to a specific node, the statistic module doesn't increase with 1...

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: you want get statistics of node?

Answer (score 2):

Node views are only counted when `node_view()` is invoked (i.e. when the node is actually viewed).

When retrieving a node via services you're not, conceptually, "viewing" it, so you shouldn't expect the view count to increase.

In order to get your desired workflow, you'll probably need to implement a custom services resource which updates the statistics manually when a node object is requested. See [How to create a custom resource with Services-3.x](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23760/how-to-create-a-custom-resource-with-services-3-x) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is Ajaxly update node counter , it not require custom module or custom resource service.

First, make sure you enable ajaxly update node counter in  statistics settings (`admin/config/system/statistics` and check`Use Ajax to increment the counter`) and then

put this code in callback of your service ( replace yournid with your content nid).

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  url: Drupal.settings.statistics.url,
  data: {"nid":yournid}
});
```

});

**update**
change

```
  url: Drupal.settings.statistics.url,
```

to

```
 url : 'http://yourdomain/modules/statistics/statistics.php',
```

[image]

Comment: Do I put this in my `js` file? What's the URL because it says `Drupal` isn't defined

Comment: in js file, exactly after you get service results, 
take look at DOM objects in firebug. you can see Drupal.

Comment: My project isn't related to Drupal, I'm only making an API call to get data from a Drupal website. So 'drupal' isn't defined in my js file

Comment: ok. I update my answer

Comment: Ok, I have the link now but since I'm using external project I can't access it because I'm not authorized

Comment: No offence, but on earth upvoted this? There's not one part of this answer which is correct

Comment: I update my answer.Dear Clive This is not the best solution  but he requires a solution and has not  Develop knowledge  :(.

Comment: I misunderstood actually, sorry, this is sort of viable. But I wouldn't recommend it; You'll have CORS to worry about, plus I really think you should let Drupal take care of when to log these stats internally

Comment: I get that, but I have unfortunately no clue about backend development. I tried reading the doc you suggested but it's all complicated for me.

Comment: Someone's going to need to code something @Greg, none of the modules involved have the functionality you require unfortunately. It's just the nature of open source software

Answer (score 0):

You can try update node counter after your service resonse with

```
if (is_numeric($nid)) {
  db_merge('node_counter')
    ->key(array('nid' => $nid))
    ->fields(array(
      'daycount' => 1,
      'totalcount' => 1,
      'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ))
    ->expression('daycount', 'daycount + 1')
    ->expression('totalcount', 'totalcount + 1')
    ->execute();
}
```

**This is back-end solution and in another answer Front-end solution Provided**

Comment: Is this for Services API call? I can get the total view when I'm on the actual page, but I'm trying to increase the number when I'm making a API call

Comment: @Greg you want manually increase view counter?

Comment: No the `Statistic module` needs to do this, but it's not working with Services

Comment: @Greg I update my answer, put this code after you service reply.

Comment: Which file should I put that? Sorry, I'm more of a front-end developer so that's new to me.

Comment: you should implement custom resource service.
let me provide another solution for you .